# Append x occurrences of a character to a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, char, append

What is the best/recommended way to add x number of occurrences of a character to a string e.g.

```
String header = "HEADER";
```

The header variable needs to have, let's say a hundred `0`'s, added to the end of it. But this number will change depending on other factors.

Answer (score 38):

How about:

```
header += new string('0', 100);
```

Of course; if you have multiple manipulations to make, consider `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("HEADER");
sb.Append('0', 100); // (actually a "fluent" API if you /really/ want...)
// other manipluations/concatenations (Append) here
string header = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Note: If you know the final size of the string, specify that as capacity when creating the StringBuilder. It minimizes reallocations, and the result is a string object without a bunch of unused memory at the end.

Answer (score 12):

This will append 100 zero characters to the string:

```
header += new string('0', 100);
```

Comment: +1 for showing the simplest possible solution, which is often best. Note however that it does **not** append characters to the string, it creates a new string with 100 zero characters, then creates another new string from the original string and the zeroes string.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
string header = "Header";
header = header.PadRight(header.Length + 100, '0');
```